# React Native Update a Flatlist Item

Tags: react-native

I want to update a specific Flatlist row when it is clicked, how can I do this? The solutions I found are all using `extraData={this.state}`, which is not working in my code.

```
const [records,setRecords] = useState([]);
//add initial data to records
...
return (
<FlatList
    data={records}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={itemData =>
        <RecordItem
            onSelect={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate({...})
                }
            } 
            onApply={()=>{
                // in my RecordItem these is a button to call onApply(), 
                and I want to update the Flatlist when I click this button

                var res = applyHandler();
                return res;
            }}
        >
        </RecordItem>
     }
/>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your flatlist item, you just have to update the data it is rendering from, in order to do this, in your `onApply` function you know the item index with which you can update the record index like:

```
const [records,setRecords] = useState([]);
//add initial data to records
...
return (
<FlatList
    data={records}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={itemData =>
        <RecordItem
            onSelect={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate({...})
                }
            } 
            onApply={()=>{
                // here you will get reference to record item index, 
                const itemIndex = itemData.index;
                const modRecords = [...records];
                modRecords[itemIndex].title = 'NEW TITLE';
                // assuming title is what you want to change
                // now just update the records using setRecords
                setRecords(modRecords);
            }}
        >
        </RecordItem>
     }
/>)
```